# Connecting PHP Api on server with React expo app localhost. Base url fails

Tags: php, reactjs, connection, fetch, expo

After hours of trying is still can't get my React Expo application (localhost http://192.168.1.113:19006/#/) to connect to my PHP api that is hosted on an external server.

The header of my api file's is as following;

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 'true'");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

When I use postman to connect and test mine /login.php file with the following json body;

*POST to: www.URLofAPIlocation.nl/subFolder/api/login.php*

```
{
    "email" : "info@email.nl",
    "password" : "Password12345"
}
```

The api returns the JWT token and succes message as expected.

```
{
    "message": "Successful login.",
    "jwt": "eyJ0eXA..... ( FULL TOKEN )"
}
```

But when I try to connect with the following functions within my react native application it try to uses the localhost base url and not the given;

```
    async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors', // Without cors it fails.
            cache: 'no-cache',
            // credentials: 'same-origin', // Not sure if needed.
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age':' 3600',
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
            body: JSON.stringify(data) 
        });
        return await response.json();
    }
    // https://www.URLofAPIlocation.nl/... and https://URLofAPIlocation.nl/ also not working
    function login(){
        postData('www.URLofAPIlocation.nl/subFolder/api/login.php', {
            email : "info@email.nl",
            password : "Password12345",
        })
        // Other option without error catching. (not working..)
            // .then((data) => {
            //     console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
            // });

        .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json()
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("End query"+ response);
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error: "+err)
                });
    }
```

I'm not sure what I do wrong since every tutorial and documentation I find the exact same setup as I am using.

The error message is as following;

```
POST http://192.168.1.17:19006/www.URLofAPIlocation.nl/subFolder/api/login.php 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems like that react expo uses it's own location as the base url and adds the url of the fetch after it. The location of the api is off course without: *http://192.168.1.17:19006/*/. I can't find where to change or remove this, so help would much be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
*Ps because of personal reasons I've hidden the exact web address of the api location and passwords. The api is hosted on an https domain and functions as expected.*

Comment: In your login function you'll need to add the protocol to the url ("https://"), otherwise it'll be treated as a relative url to your current location (http://192.168.1.17:19006)